Subfolders without ancestors on IMAP server
Conceptual question about subfolders and IMAP, for which I haven't found an answer in any of the specs.
Say I have the following folders (written in maildir notation, with . being the hierarchy delimiter);

INBOX
Sub.Folder

Importantly, notice there is not a folder called Sub, but there is a Sub -> Folder.

Is this legal? Or is Sub required to exist, at least as a \NoSelect or \NonExistent mailbox on the server?
Assuming the above is legal, whose job is it to create a virtual Sub folder for the purposes of mailbox presentation. Is it the server's to include a Sub as \NonExistent in the LIST response, or it the client's job to figure out, after receiving the LIST response, that there is no Sub, and that Sub.Folder should logically be nested underneath a virtual folder such as that? For example, Thunderbird-based clients seem to do this automatically.

In the latter case, is the appropriate algorithm to scan the mailboxes returned, see which mailboxes are subfolders prefixed by a parent folder that doesn't exist in the returned response, and create virtual mailboxes to display as if they were returned \NonExistent? This is my best guess heuristically, but I can't pin this down in an RFC anywhere.

This is a case for Postel's Principle (which, again, does not mean what most people think). But this is a case where it does apply — an underspecified corner of an RFC.
You, as client, don't see a requirement for servers to do the right thing, so you should be liberal and cover the case where they don't send anything about the Sub mailbox. Servers authors don't see a requirement that clients handle the case where it's missing, so they should be conservative and send a \NoSelect '\HasChildren mailbox.
